# Updating a column in the DB based on current user changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page, that displays a bunch of information fetched from the Database. Also, there is 2 date columns that are editable. After you hit `submit` the data is changed on the page as well as the database. I also have the user identity being showed on the page. For instance, whoever is using this computer, their name and email are being displayed.

**My dilemma:**
I am able to fetch the name and email using this in my controller:

```
using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);
            agtName = up.Name;
            username = up.EmailAddress;
            TempData["loginName"] = agtName;
            TempData["Email"] = username;
        }


   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdatePlannedDate(string ids, string Date1, string Date2)
    {
        model = new Hello();
        Entity db = new Entity();
        List<Hello> list = new List<Hello>();
        string[] IDS = ids.Split(',');
        string[] Date1S = Date1.Split(',');
        string[] Date2S = Date2.Split(',');

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < IDS.Length; i++)
            {
                if (IDS[i] != null && IDS[i] != "")
                {
                    Hello item = new Hello { R_ID = IDS[i], Date_Two = DateTime.Parse(Date2S[i]), Date_One = DateTime.Parse(Date1S[i]) };
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }
            foreach (var row in db.table1)  
            {
                foreach (var row2 in db.table2) 
                {
                    if (row.U_ID == row2.C_ID)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            if (row.U_ID == item.R_ID)
                            {
                                var cd = db.Table2.Where(x => x.C_ID == row.U_ID).First();
                                cd.PlanDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date_Two);
                                cd.PlanDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date_One);
                                cd.Last_Updated_By = username; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true, msg = "Updated" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, msg = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

However, in my view class, there is a column called `Last_Updated_By` (being populated from the database) and I want current users email address in place of it after the `Submit` button is clicked (the data is being passed to the controller via an ajax call). There is data currently present in that column.

View class:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Last_Updaed_By)</td>
```

I wanted to get some ideas on how I would be able to achieve this. Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: I suspect you can directly set item.Last_Updated_By in the controller. But I don't know for sure without seeing your controller method.  Could you add the full code of your controller method to your question?

Comment: @JeffreyRennie Posted the controller method